# how to use MAX for multiple values in dyamnmic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query when I'm using static Dynamic pivot it is working fine

**Static Script** :

```
Select Name, tableName,MAX([2017-07-10])[2017-07-10],MAX([2017-07-09])[2017-07-09]
        from (
SELECT      Target_Db_Name,
            Target_Tbl_Name,
            Cnt
    FROM Table1 l 

            WHERE Name='Employee' AND
                     dt >= CAST(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date))T
PIVOT (MAX(cnt)FOR dt IN ([2017-07-10],[2017-07-09]) )PVT
GROUP BY  Name, tableName
```

when I'm trying to implement dynamic query in the same query I'm confused to get max values for multiple comma separated data values

**Dynamic Script** :

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(dt) + ',' FROM (select distinct CONVERT(DATE,t)Start_dt from Events
WHERE Start_dt >= CAST(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date) ) as tmp ORDER BY Start_dt desc
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) 


Select @query = '

Select Name, tableName,'+@cols+'
        from (
SELECT      Name,
            tableName,
            Cnt
    FROM  Table1 l 

            WHERE Name=''Employee'' AND
                     Start_dt >= CAST(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date))T
PIVOT (MAX(Cnt)FOR Start_dt IN ('+@cols+') )PVT
GROUP BY  Name, tableName
'

EXEC   (@query)
```

So here date values are coming like this

**([2017-07-10]),([2017-07-09])** in dynamic how to apply

**MAX([2017-07-10]),MAX([2017-07-09])**

how to get max for each date in Dynamic Pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to get the `Max` aggregate in column list

```
SET @cols = stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ','+Quotename(CONVERT(DATE, Start_dt)) 
             FROM   Events
             WHERE  Start_dt >= Cast(Dateadd(day, -1, Getdate()) AS DATE)
             ORDER  BY Start_dt DESC
             FOR xml path('')) ,1,1,'')
--Print @cols

SET @select_cols = stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',Max('+Quotename(CONVERT(DATE, Start_dt))+') as '+Quotename(CONVERT(DATE, t)) 
             FROM   Events
             WHERE  Start_dt >= Cast(Dateadd(day, -1, Getdate()) AS DATE)
             ORDER  BY Start_dt DESC
             FOR xml path('')) ,1,1,'')
--Print @select_cols

Select @query = '

Select Name, tableName,'+@select_cols+'
        from (
SELECT      Name,
            tableName,
            Cnt
    FROM  Table1 l 

            WHERE Name=''Employee'' AND
                     Start_dt >= CAST(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date))T
PIVOT (MAX(Cnt)FOR Start_dt IN ('+@cols+') )PVT
GROUP BY  Name, tableName
'

EXEC   (@query)
```

**Note :** Your current method to convert rows into csv's isn't guaranteed to work all the time. I have used for `xml path()` method to do the same